# Combine two objects into one

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm preparing to pass values to a method:

```
 private string BuildMessage(int templateID, string body, object data)
```

where the **data** param is an array of name/value pairs. To prepare my values for that **data** param I need to combine the properties of a strongly typed class  with the values of a simple 2d array.

What's the best way to merge those values?

Comment: Can you give examples of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Is there a reason that a generic dictionary will not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get the properties and teir values via Reflection, like this:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetParameters(object data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return null;

        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in data.GetType().GetProperties())
            parameters.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(data, null).ToString());
        return parameters;
    }
```

Merging the two dictionaries shouldn't need further explanation :)